# FreePBX: Record automatic originated calls

Tags: asterisk, recording, pbx, asteriskami, freepbx

We have a bunch of analog telephones and a few softphones and IP-phones in our office. Analog telephones run by a telephone exchange Samsung OfficeServ 7200 connected to a FreePBX. FreePBX has extensions for each analog telephone for call recording. When I try to call manually from analog telephone call is being recorded, all is fine. But when I use "channel originate" command from Asterisk CLI FreePBX does not record this call.

Command I use in Asterisk CLI looks like this:
channel originate DAHDI/i2/134 extension 8903XXXXXXX@from-internal
Where 134 is local analog telephone and 8903XXXXXXX is my mobile phone. What can I do to record originated calls as well?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices

1) Use Freepbx. If you use freepbx, you have generate calls via call Local/XXX@from-internal/n and set CALLERID acordinly. Recording will work just ok

2) Use custom code. If so, **YOU** are responsible for any logic like macro-record-enable or custom monitoring, so you have do additional dialplan to handle that.

Comment: I added CallerrID option to AMI request like this:

Action: Originate
Channel: DAHDI/i2/$hostnumber
Callerid: $hostnumber
Exten: $targetnumber
Context: from-internal

That worked, thank you very much. : )